# how to force child spring boot jar to read properties from parent spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

i have a spring boot project which i am building as a jar and using this in another spring boot project as a maven dependency, this jar requires some properties which should be picked from parent spring boot, there is application.properties in jar itself, it it neither picking properties from it's application.properties neither parent application.properties

i am generating the jar for project1 using repackage goal

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
        <execution>
         <id>repackage</id>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

in the jar i have defined HelloClientConfiguration which will pick properties from application.properties  and my other classes are expecting these properties

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="abc")
@Data
public class HelloClientConfiguration {

private String serviceKey;
private String apiID;
 }
```

i am defining the application.properties in parent spring boot project as

```
abc.serviceKey = xyl
abc.apiID = abc
```

i tried defining these properties both in child and parent, then only parent left child application.properties empty but no luck

my understanding is that as jar in running in the same spring environment as parent spring boot so if properties are not available local in jar then it should look up in the parent for properties?

Comment: Did you try auto configuration in your project 1?

Comment: look at spring's documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html here 24.3 Application Property Files. You can give a spring.config.location and point to a different properties file.

Comment: @Julia how do i configure project1 so that  project1 looks for properties from project2

Comment: Set a beanconfiguration in your parent project and load it in your child.